# Adding values in two columns and storing to a third column using derby, netbeans and jsp?

Tags: jsp, netbeans, sum, derby

I would like to add data to two pre-existing columns and then run a query through a jsp page that adds up the data row-wise. For example, if columns A contains 100 and column B contains 150, I want to set it up so that column C shows 150. I'm working with Derby database that comes with Netbeans. Any help or pointers are much appreciated.

I can print the summated value easily, but the update function is tripping me. This is what I have so far.

```
    String query = "SELECT * FROM EXPERIMENTALTABLE1";
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    Statement rt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet ts = st.executeQuery(query);
    int totalrowwise=0;
    while (ts.next()){
        totalrowwise = ts.getInt(1)+ts.getInt(2);
        out.print("totalrowwise: "+totalrowwise);
        rt.executeUpdate("UPDATE EXPERIMANTALTABLE1 SET SUMCOLUMN=(ts.getInt(1)+ts.getInt(2))");
        %><br><%}%>
```

rt.executeUpdate("UPDATE EXPERIMANTALTABLE1 SET SUMCOLUMN=(ts.getInt(1)+ts.getInt(2))"); // this is the line getting me in trouble

Answer (score 1):

So after a fair bit of unsolicited errors, I have an inelegant code that, however, seems to do what I want it to do. I shall now get down to prettying it, but in the meantime, anyone stuck at the same spot can get an idea of what I did. Here's the code.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>JSP Page</title></head>
<body>
    WORKING CODE TO ADD TWO COLUMNS<br>
<%
String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ExperimentalDatabase";
String username = "username";
String password = "password";
String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE2";
String updater = "";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
int count = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    count++;
    %><br>---<br><%}%>
<%
for (int c = 1; c <= count; c++) {
    updater = "UPDATE TABLE2 SET SumValue = value1+value2 WHERE userid = " + c;
    st.executeUpdate(updater);
    out.print("Row "+c+" updated");
%><br><%}%>
```

Comment: If you're intending to perform that `UPDATE` statement for every row in your table, you don't need a `WHERE` clause, and you don't need to count up all your rows and then loop through each userid. You can just run `update table2 set sumvalue=value1+value2' once, and it will perform that update for each row.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Bryan. Actually, I tried something like that, but it ended up assigning the sum of the last row values in the to each of the rows in the third table. It looked a bit like this.

Value1   Value2    SumValue
10           20           50
5             15           50
20            30          50

couldn't get past that, hence the convoluted way. I'll try it again today. Will update if it clicks.